# Get Parent from Child in Laravel without extra query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a small system with two models: `Product`, `ProductPrice`.

Here is the Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['prices'];

    public $tax_rate = 0.2;

    public function prices ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductPrice::class);
    }
}
```

I put the `tax_rate` constant here for more clarity, but in real world, it is handled by another relation.

**The most important thing here is that the `tax_rate` is a property of the `Product` model**

Here is the `ProductPrice` model:

```
class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['tax_included_price'];

    public function getTaxIncludedPriceAttribute()
    {
        return (1 + $this->product->tax_rate) * $this->price;
    }

    public function product ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Now let's imagine that I need to use `$product->toArray()` on some model. With this example, I will get an Exception for infinite loop because my `getTaxIncludedPriceAttribute()` method makes a new request to find the `product` attribute.

**So could I access the `Product` parent in the `ProductPrice` model if I access to it through the parent, and without making an extra query**

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem with a handmade solution, not sure of implementation, but it works like I want it to work.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['pricesRelation'];

    protected $appends = ['prices'];

    public $tax_rate = 0.2;

    public function pricesRelation ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductPrice::class);
    }

    public function getPricesAttribute ()
    {
        $collection = new Collection();

        foreach($this->pricesRelation as $relation) {
            $relation->loadProduct($this);
            $collection->add($relation);
        }

        return $relation;
    }
}
```

As you see, I run a `$relation->loadProduct($this);` to define parent on relation without re querying it...

```
class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['tax_included_price'];

    protected $loaded_product;

    public function getTaxIncludedPriceAttribute()
    {
        $tax_rate = is_null($loaded_product) ? $this->product->tax_rate : $this->loaded_product->tax_rate;
        return (1 + $tax_rate) * $this->price;
    }

    public function loadProduct (Product $product) 
    {
        $this->loaded_product = $product;
    }

    public function product ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```